# How can i download my audios from FirebaseStorage in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

if can anyone write the code to run in flutter version 3.7.3 please i will be so appreciated

How can i download my audios from FirebaseStorage in flutter app and show them in ListView and make bottom to play them for know i have liek 10000 audios in my firebase_storage please some help if so❤

Answer (score 0):

If you are geting a Url or audio file the you can simple pass the url of your audio file in package: [audioplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer)

**Code:**

```dart
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);
    
    play() async {
        int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
        if (result == 1) {
          // success
        }
      }
```

for more controll and custumization you can also use : audio_service: